# Can a species populated solely by males be saved from extinction?

Tags: reproduction, taxonomy, species, extinction

How, if possible, can a species be saved from extinction if the only surviving population are males that cannot reproduce with each other?

Comment: The article does not say it died. I vote to close this question.

Comment: It does not say anywhere in the article that the female died.

Comment: This question does not apply just to the linked species.

Comment: If the "males" can self-reproduce: yes, if not: no.

Comment: Than it's too broad and pob

Comment: Its more complex, I am going to provide a quick answer.

Comment: "How, if possible, can a species be saved from extinction if the only surviving population are males"... it sounds like you are questioning a specific paper/article/book etc that claims "the only surviving population are males" or something like that. Is it? if yes; then please give a link to that article. If no; then the question does not make sense because why only males of a population would survive.

Comment: I would request moderators to revert the edit because otherwise the question does not make useful sense. It looks the OP seeking skeptic analyses on a particular blog... not about whole living world.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Consider the fact that a lot of species are critically endangered due to habitat destruction and climate change, populations will dwindle and there is a chance that the population, however small, will only be populated by one gender. Is that not possible?

Comment: May be the bloggers meant some other method of propagation like gene bank and ivf etc.

Comment: In 2012 we weren't able to save an species with one male and no females https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonesome_George .

Comment: @Pere Would it be possible for a sole female to save their species?

Comment: Well, in 1999 they couldn't but in 2003 they tried again.https://www.nationalgeographic.com/magazine/2013/04/species-revival-bringing-back-extinct-animals/ However, I must admit that neither the failures nor the hope for success were related with the fact that the last individual was a female. I haven't been able to find examples more similar to the question, with several individuals but all of them of the same sex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer only deals with **theorical feasability**

> Can a species populated solely by males be saved from extinction?

Short answer : No, not with certainty

Nuanced : yes, in some species, it *could* be possible

It varies in function of how you determinate the sex of your species.
Sex determination is a wide topic, see the [appropriate wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex-determination_system)

Some reptilian species are not sexually determined by chromosomes but by temperature. An example is the painted turtle, of which thermal sex determination has been studied by Carrie Lynne Morjan in an [article](http://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2011&context=rtd) titled *Temperature-dependent sex determination and the
evolutionary potential for sex ratio in the painted
turtle, Chrysemys picta*

Thermal sex determination allows you to get 2 different sexes from the "same" genome, as temperature will be the driver of the hormonal differentiation.

[*Cross-species cloning: influence of cytoplasmic factors on development*, by Sun and Zhu](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4048095/#b11) states that cross species cloning has been successfully made with fishes and mammals.

> Nevertheless, cross-species NT has succeeded in cloning some endangered mammals, such as the gaur
>
> In fish, a type of relatively primitive vertebrate, cross-species NT [nuclear transfer] could be achieved in quite a few genetically distant species

It means we are able to use as a mother and egg-layer a different, albeit related, species.

We can, with a massive grain of salt, hypothesize that we could, in a specie solely constituted of sperm producing male, use the oocyte of another specie to clone it, then use the thermal differentiation to make a female out of our clone.

However, I am not aware of any information about how much genome and spermatozoids genetic payload is modified by the sex differentiation. Therefore, it is possible that sex-determined genes **cannot** produce a sexually naive clone.
For more information, and if you want to research more about it, I recommend you to see the current state-of the art in de-differenciation technics and DNA-demethylation for cloning.

I hope I provided a sufficient answer for you.